# How to modify a java timer interval after scheduling it for a fixed rate in android?

Tags: android, service, timer

I have a service which has one Timer. I call `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` in the `onStart()` callback method. But I have to alter the timer interval depending on the value of a variable. I found no function for timer to alter its interval. So I thought to cancel the timer and re-schedule when that condition is met. But I am checking the condition with in the timerTask itself. So when I tried to cancel the timer in the TimerTask, it throws `IllegalStateException`. Can anybody give me some solution?

Answer (score 0):

A timer can only be scheduled once. If IllegalStateException isn't happening when you call cancel(), but when you try to reschedule the timer, just reinstantiate the timer and then schedule it. Otherwise, I'm not sure.

Comment: A `Timer` isn't scheduled at all, let alone rescheduled, but a `TimerTask` can be rescheduled as often as you like. This seems to be just guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Netiher `Timer.cancel()` nor `TimerTask.cancel()` throws `IllegalStateException`. That is thrown when you try to schedule a task on a cancelled `Timer.`

Solution: don't cancel the `Timer`; cancel the `TimerTask`.