# How to change a java timer's interval

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm working on an android Tetris game. And an IllegalStateException occurred when executing

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate (task, 0L, milliseconds);
```

in

```
public void setTimerInterval (int milliseconds) {
    timer.cancel ();
    timer = new Timer ();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate (task, 0L, milliseconds);
}
```

Am I doing this wrongly or something?
I need to cancel the timer and create a new one because I cannot change the interval of the timer unless you schedule a new task for it, right?

I read a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593134/how-to-modify-a-java-timer-interval-after-scheduling-it-for-a-fixed-rate-in-andr) and here is a quote of one of the answers:

> A timer can only be scheduled once. If IllegalStateException isn't happening when you call cancel(), but when you try to reschedule the timer, just reinstantiate the timer and then schedule it. Otherwise, I'm not sure.

I didn't use the accepted answer of the that question because it's about pausing and resuming the timer.

I reinstantiated the timer as shown above but there is still a IllegalStateException.

Comment: I didn't provide a stack trace because I don't know how to do it in the question editor. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The answer your quoted is nonsense.

Comment: Oh really? I thought that is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do the task here
        handler.postDelayed(this, milliseconds); // set time here to refresh textView
    }
});
```

Make the `milliseconds` global and change that, maybe that would be a better solution.

Comment: You mean adding this to the setTimerInterval method? But milliseonds is a parameter, how can I make that global?

Comment: i mean using this instead of a timer. with the post delayed you can run a task after X milliseconds

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Hope it's a solution for your problem. Let know when your done

Answer (score 0):

> How to change a java timer's interval

Java `Timers` don't have intervals. Timer *tasks* have intervals.

Solution: cancel and reschedule the `TimerTask`, not the `Timer`.